# Formato de código: ¿qué formato usar para texto largo, por ejemplo mensajes de error?

Tags: discusión, formato

Hay algo que veo con frecuencia en las preguntas o respuestas de SO.

Cuando se escribe un texto largo, como mensajes de error, algunos le dan el formato de código, por ejemplo:

```
[1/2] SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]La conversión del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo.

[2/2] QueryException in Connection.php line 729: SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]La conversión del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo. (SQL: insert into [users] ([name], [email], [password], [updated_at], [created_at]) values (pruebaname, emailname@name.com,
```

Evidentemente, a la derecha puede haber información útil para resolver el problema, pero a veces lo que buscamos podría quedar muyyyy a la derecha.

Si lo formateamos como una cita, la diferencia es grande:

> [1/2] SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]La conversión del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un
>   valor fuera de intervalo.
>
> [2/2] QueryException in Connection.php line 729: SQLSTATE[22007]:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]La conversión
>   del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de
>   intervalo. (SQL: insert into [users] ([name], [email], [password],
>   [updated_at], [created_at]) values (pruebaname, emailname@name.com

Tenemos en una sola vista toda la información.

¿Se habían percatado de esto? ¿Cómo suelen uds formatear esos textos largos, como formato de código o como cita textual? ¿Hay algo en formato de código que de automáticamente saltos para ver todo en su conjunto sin tener que desplazarse a la derecha?

Comment: Para los stacktrace, prefiero usar cita en lugar de código, por lo mismo que expones aquí.

Comment: Para los errores uso ">"

Comment: para mensajes de error cortos y que contienen nombres de variables, al igual que @x4mp73r uso ">" añadiendo los 4 espacios para que formatee a codigo

Comment: @x4mp73r eso es citas :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Lo se, lo comenté para hacer ver al usuario que hay varias personas que usamos lo mismo, ¿tiene algo de malo que haya repetido tu comentario?

Comment: @x4mp73r genial que tú lo sepas, pero al parecer otros usuarios desconocen esto. Lo noto porque el tuyo tiene voto a favor a diferencia del mío (o será que simplemente me odian :) ).

Comment: @Luiggi: +1, te queremos también :)

Comment: Yo prefiero formatear los errores como código.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Texto impreso en pantalla y errores cortos

Para cualquier texto impreso como salida del programa, descubrí que la forma que más me gusta utilizar es el formato de código dentro de una cita.

[image: Código dentro de cita con texto "Hola Mundo.\nFin del programa."]

Que se logra seleccionando el texto y haciendo click en [image: botón "{ }"] (o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>)
...y luego seleccionándolo de nuevo y haciendo click en [image: botón "comillas"] (o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>)

En el editor, es un `>` seguido de 5 espacios.

```
>     Hola mundo.
>     Fin del programa.
```

---

### Stack traces demasiado anchas

**Opción 1. Como código con saltos de línea dentro de una cita**
Que se logra seleccionando el texto y haciendo click en [image: botón "comillas"] (o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>)

... y luego englobando a todo el texto en etiquetas `<pre>` ... `</pre>`.

[image: código con saltos de línea dentro de una cita]

- Al formatear primero como cita, se generan automáticamente saltos de línea a los 70 caracteres.

En el editor queda así (todo dentro de una etiqueta **`<pre>`**)

```
> <pre>[1/2] SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]La conversión del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un
> valor fuera de intervalo.
> 
> [2/2] QueryException in Connection.php line 729: SQLSTATE[22007]:
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]La conversión
> del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de
> intervalo. (SQL: insert into [users] ([name], [email], [password],
> [updated_at], [created_at]) values (pruebaname, emailname@name.com</pre>
```

**Opción 2. Como cita**

Como cita, con texto de ancho variable:

[image: Cita]

Seleccionando el texto y haciendo click en [image: botón "comillas"] (o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>)

En el editor se ve así:

```
> [1/2] SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]La conversión del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un
> valor fuera de intervalo.
> 
> [2/2] QueryException in Connection.php line 729: SQLSTATE[22007]:
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]La conversión
> del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de
> intervalo. (SQL: insert into [users] ([name], [email], [password],
> [updated_at], [created_at]) values (pruebaname, emailname@name.com
```

---

### Usa tu criterio

Si bien son reglas generales de formato a utilizar, la mejor regla es utilizar tu buen juicio para evaluar qué quedaría mejor. Al fin y al cabo, es tu publicación. Formateala como mejor creas que quede.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. +1